# How do I align a third node below the exact middle of a horizontal line between two nodes situated above?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have found [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559313/how-to-position-a-node-centered-above-two-other-nodes)  two [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117063/tikz-center-node-below-2-other-nodes) which are similar to mine. However, my problem requires me to adjust the vertical distance between a horizontal line and the north point of a node, due to the different number of rows used in my diagram. In other words, I need to exactly align the middle of a horizontal connector with the north point of a node below. I need to do more work amending the vertical spacing, but that can wait until my current problem is solved.

I am currently trying to construct a diagram of data flow that, in some cases, has two sets of data contributing to a single cleaned set of data. So this is a series of lines-between-two-nodes-on-the-same-horizontal-plane and vertical-arrow-to-outcome-dataset. This is in a chapter of my dissertation, with the chapter being called by

```
\include{Chapters/ChapterName}
```

I know how to find the mid-point of the line between two nodes, e.g.

```
($ (TopLeft.east) !.5! (TopRight.west) $) -- (Below.north);
```

where the code specifies the mid-point of the line from which to draw.

But how do I position `Below` so I don't have to do some type of offset from `TopLeft` or `TopRight`? Currently I am doing this type of specification for `Below':

```
    \node[rectangle, rounded corners, below left = .5cm and -.5cm of TopRight] (BL) {My below \\ node};
```

I'm spending a lot of time trying (and often failing) to get the north point of `Below` exactly below the mid-point defined in the line between `TopLeft` and `TopRight`. As you can see, I've been trying to wrangle this with `below left` and `below right` measurements. And these become incorrect every time I adjust the text in the box(es) above as it changes the relative positioning of the boxes. So I have the start of the arrow correctly positioned on the half-way point of the horizontal lines, I have the arrow correctly connecting to the north point of the node below, but I can't get the position of that latter node correct relative to the mid-point of the horizontal connecting line above it.

Basically, `north` should be on the same y-coordinate as the mid-point of the line connecting the two nodes above it.

I'm using a special document class, but this should work for any general Latex class. The boxes below will look weird because my real node text is much longer in every case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}      %get the page layout right
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                        %turn off hypenation globally
\usepackage{microtype}                              %better typesetting, affects justification and punctuation
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}                                    % typeset URL's reasonably
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                          % default bracket type is round
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}                               %typeset tables better
\usepackage{multirow}                               %allow merge look across table rows
%\usepackage{placeins}                              %fix table floats!
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                                 % must be imported BEFORE tikz
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}                             %sensible cross-referencing *****MUST BE PLACED AFTER HYPERREF PACKAGE IF THAT PACKAGE IS USED*****
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
%\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{spreadtab} % can't get this to work
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw, align=center, arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}, font=\footnotesize]
\node[rectangle, rounded corners] (SAS) {BOX 1 has quite a bit of text \\ across 2 rows};

\node[rectangle, rounded corners, above left = .5cm and .1cm of SAS] (PD) {Box 2 has less text than Box 1};
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, above right = .5cm and .1cm of SAS] (TAS) {Box 3 has similar length to 2};

\node[rectangle, rounded corners, right = .8cm of SAS] (SLS) {Box 4 has this length};
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, below left = .5cm and -.5cm of SLS] (SLC) {Box 5 smaller than box 1 \\ and is 2 rows};
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, below = .7cm of SLC] (SWA) {Box 6 is back to 1 row};

\node[rectangle, rounded corners, below = .7cm of SWA] (HHS) {Box 7 has about the same amount \\ of text as box 1};
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, below = .7cm of HHS] (SPH) {Box 8 just 1 row};

\node[rectangle, rounded corners, right = .8 of SPH] (SRI) {Box 9 is in \\ two rows again}; 
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, below right = .7cm and -1.6cm of SPH] (CIS) {Box 10 is one row};  

 \node[rectangle, rounded corners, right = .8cm of CIS] (EI) {Box 11 has two \\ rows}; 
 
    
\draw[solid] (PD.east) -- (TAS.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (PD.east) !.5! (TAS.west) $) -- (SAS.north);
\draw[solid] (SAS.east) -- (SLS.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (SAS.east) !.5! (SLS.west) $) -- (SLC.north);
\draw[arrow] (SLC.south) -- (SWA.north);
\draw[arrow] (SWA.south) -- (HHS.north);
\draw[arrow] (HHS.south) -- (SPH.north);
\draw[solid] (SPH.east) -- (SRI.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (SPH.east) !.5! (SRI.west) $) -- (CIS.north);
\draw[solid] (CIS.east) -- (EI.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Process used to construct data.}
\label{fig:SPOutline}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flow chart you can draw on the following way:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners,
                     font=\footnotesize, align=center},
     arrow/.style = {thick, -Stealth},
                        ]
\node (SAS) {BOX 1 has quite a bit of text \\ across 2 rows};
\node (PD)  [above  left = 5mm and 1mm of SAS]  {Box 2 has less text than Box 1};
\node (TAS) [above right = 5mm and 1mm of SAS]  {Box 3 has similar length to 2};
%
\node (SLS) [right = 8mm of SAS]    {Box 4 has this length};
\node (SLC) [below = 5mm of $(SAS.south east)!0.5!(SLS.south west)$]
                                    {Box 5 smaller than box 1 \\ and is 2 rows};
\node (SWA) [below = 7mm of SLC]    {Box 6 is back to 1 row};

\node (HHS) [below = 7mm of SWA]    {Box 7 has about the same amount \\ of text as box 1};
\node (SPH) [below = 7mm of HHS]    {Box 8 just 1 row};

\node (SRI) [right = 8mm of SPH]     {Box 9 is in \\ two rows again};
\node (CIS) [below = 7mm of $(SPH.south east)!0.5!(SRI.south west)$]   {Box 10 is one row};

\node (EI)  [right = 8mm of CIS]    {Box 11 has two \\ rows};

\draw[solid] (PD.east) -- (TAS.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (PD.east) !.5! (TAS.west) $) -- (SAS.north);
\draw[solid] (SAS.east) -- (SLS.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (SAS.east) !.5! (SLS.west) $) -- (SLC.north);
\draw[arrow] (SLC.south) -- (SWA.north);
\draw[arrow] (SWA.south) -- (HHS.north);
\draw[arrow] (HHS.south) -- (SPH.north);
\draw[solid] (SPH.east) -- (SRI.west);
\draw[arrow] ($ (SPH.east) !.5! (SRI.west) $) -- (CIS.north);
\draw[solid] (CIS.east) -- (EI.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Process used to construct data.}
\label{fig:SPOutline}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, i would more prefer the following flowchart:

[image]

where are employed Ti*k*Z library `chains` and his macro `join=by ...`:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   arr/.style = {semithick, -Stealth},
node distance = 7mm and 8mm,
     N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, text width=#1,
                 font=\footnotesize, align=center}, 
  N/.default = 12em,
 start chain
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain=going below, join=by arr}]
\node (SAS) {BOX 1 has quite a bit of text \\ across 2 rows};
\node (SLC) {Box 5 smaller than box 1 \\ and is 2 rows};
\node (SWA) {Box 6 is back to 1 row};
\node (HHS) {Box 7 has about the same amount \\ of text as box 1};
\node (SPH) {Box 8 just 1 row};
\node (CIS) {Box 10 is one row};
    \end{scope}
\node (PD)  [N,above  left=of SAS.north]  {Box 2 has less text than Box 1};
\node (TAS) [N,above right=of SAS.north]  {Box 3 has similar length to 2};
    \draw[arr]  (PD)  -| ([xshift=-1em] SAS.north);
    \draw[arr]  (TAS) -| ([xshift=+1em] SAS.north);
%
\node (SLS) [N=8em, right=of SAS]    {Box 4 has this length};
    \draw[arr]  (SLS.south) -- ++ (0,-4mm) -|  ([xshift=+1em] SLC.north) ;
%
\node (SRI) [N=8em, right=of SPH]     {Box 9 is in \\ two rows again};
    \draw[arr]  (SRI.south) -- ++ (0,-2mm) -|  ([xshift=+1em] CIS.north) ;
%
\node (EI)  [N=8em,right = 8mm of CIS]    {Box 11 has two \\ rows};

\draw[arr] (CIS) -- (EI);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Process used to construct data.}
\label{fig:SPOutline}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first one is exactly what I wanted (these are data structures and they are being operated on together to construct the following data structure). Also, thanks for cleaning up the node structure text!

Answer (score 5):

You can actually position a node below the calculated center of two other nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[draw] (n1) at (-5,0) {Node 1};
  \node[draw] (n2) at (5,0) {Node 2};

  \node[draw, below = 1cm of {$(n1) !.5! (n2)$}] {Node 3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]